# How to hide row in html

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to hide all class row which is used from bootstrap using jquery function `$('#divid').css("visibility", 'hidden');` but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicates of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410415/hide-table-rows-that-dont-have-a-certain-class
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612379/jquery-hide-all-elements-with-certain-class-except-one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569457/hide-all-table-rows-that-lack-a-particular-class
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474429/jquery-to-hide-rows-that-do-not-have-a-certain-class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - get all divs inside a div with class ".container"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977699/jquery-get-all-divs-inside-a-div-with-class-container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hide by class:**

```
$('.divclass').hide();
```

**Hide by id:**

```
 $('#divid').hide();
```

**Hide by tag:**

```
 $('div').hide(); // all div tag will be hide
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to hide all class

so use class, not id ))

```
$('.divclass').css("visibility", 'hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  Remove rows classes

```
$("#divid .row").removeClass("row");
```